# Putting a View on top of Scroll View while Scrolling down

Tags: android, scrollview

Basically, I have a Scroll View and it contains several child inside Linear Layout. Now, I want to show a View constantly on the top of the screen when it is scrolled down.If it is scrolled up everything should be as it was earlier.
Can anyone just help me out? Any help would be appreciated! (Thanks in advance).

Comment: This is difficult if not impossible to do when the "sticky" view is a child of the scrollview. Usually you would place the sticky view _outside_ the scrollview, leave a placeholder where it would be, and move it by listening to scroll events on the scrollview.

Comment: Thanks guys. I found out a library which does the same work! (StickyScrollView)

Comment: post your xml file @abhishek

Answer (score 0):

Define a ObservableScrollView class entends ScrollView.
Then write your layout xml like this:

```
<RelativeLayout>    
<View/>
<ObservableScrollView>
</ObservableScrollView>
<RelativeLayout>
```

In ObservableScrollView class,focus on this onScrollChanged function.
Change the visibility of your target view  by param 'y'.